# Headphones not detected by Ubuntu 16.04. Output of Alsa info in the details

Tags: drivers, sound, 16.04, headphones

I own an alienware 17 R3. Eversince I installed ubuntu, I have been facing one or the other driver problems.

First it was WiFi. I updated the Linux firmware to 1.158 and WiFi started detecting networks
Then, display. I installed the proprietary drivers (361.45.11) and that gave me horrible screen tearing issue.
Now, headphones. I own a Sony MDR-XB450 headphones and it is not being detected. Sound keeps playing through external speakers

Any help regarding this would be appreaciated. Output of Alsa info is given below

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=eab9df3cd1fbe887705f41603d8d9cc2c2833911

Thanks a lot